# Delphi Firedac Update don't apply modified

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firedac

I can not update rows in the database with the following instructions:

```
fdquery1.Edit;  
fdquery1.fieldByName('prova').AsString := 'asdasd';

fdquery1.Open;
```

Why? i must use another property of TFDQuery for 
changes to take effect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After [`TDataSet.Edit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Edit) you must call [`TDataSet.Post`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Post) to persist the changed values.

```
fdquery1.Edit;  
fdquery1.fieldByName('prova').AsString := 'asdasd';
fdquery1.Post;
```

The [documentation also has a sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Editing_Records) for that

BTW: I am not sure why you want to open the dataset again?